# Vue screen that refreshes periodically, done safely

Tags: javascript, vue.js, timer

I have a page in Vue/Nuxt that needs to refresh a list of items every few seconds. This is an SPA that does an Axios fetch to a server to get updated information. At the moment, I have something like this:

```
methods: {
  doRefresh() {
    setTimeout(function() {
      // trigger server fetch here  
      doRefresh();
    }, 5000);
  }
}
```

It works, unless the other code in doRefresh throws an error, in which case the refreshing stops, or somehow the code gets called twice, and I get two timers going at the same time.

An alternative is call setInterval() only once. The trouble with that is that it keeps going even after I leave the page. I could store the reference returned by the setInterval(), and then stop it in a destroyed() hook. But again, an error might prevent that from happening.

Is there a safe and reliable way to run a timer on a Vue page, and destroy it when the user leaves the page?

Answer (score 1):

This approach together with try-catch is a way to go, have a look at this snippet:
https://codepen.io/alexbrohshtut/pen/YzXjNeB

```
<div id="app">
  <wrapper/>
</div>
```

```
Vue.component("interval-component", {
  template: `
    <div>  {{lastRefreshed}}
      <button @click="init">Start</button></div>`,
  data() {
    return {
      timeoutId: undefined,
      lastRefreshed: undefined
    };
  },
  methods: {
    doJob() {
      if (Math.random() > 0.9) throw new Error();
      this.lastRefreshed = new Date();
      console.log("Job done");
    },
    init() {
      if (this.timeoutId) return;
      this.run();
    },
    run() {
      console.log("cycle started");
      const vm = this;
      this.timeoutId = setTimeout(function() {
        try {
          vm.doJob();
        } catch (e) {
          console.log(e);
        } finally {
          vm.run();
        }
      }, 2000);
    }
  },
  destroyed() {
    clearTimeout(this.timeoutId);
    console.log("Destroyed");
  }
});
Vue.component("wrapper", {
  template: `<div>  <button @click="create" v-if="destroyed"> Create</button>
    <button v-else @click="destroy">Destroy</button>

    <interval-component v-if="!destroyed" /></div>`,
  data() {
    return {
      destroyed: true
    };
  },
  methods: {
    destroy() {
      this.destroyed = true;
    },
    create() {
      this.destroyed = false;
    }
  }
});
new Vue({
  el: "#app"
});
```